# Using local Sass variables in mixin

Tags: sass, scss-mixins

I have a bunch of variables that are defined for use in a light/dark theme (two separate files):

```css
$primary-1: red;
$primary-2: green;
```

and I don't want to declare them all twice when consuming them. I wrote a mixin that does the assignments for me:

```css
@mixin assign-vars {
  --primary-1: #{$primary-1};
  --primary-2: #{$primary-2};
}
```

and I would like to use it like this:

```css
@import 'assign-vars';

:root,
:root[data-theme='light'] {
  @import 'light-theme-variables';
  @include assign-vars;
}

:root[data-theme='dark'] {
  @import 'dark-theme-variables';
  @include assign-vars;
}
```

but this does not work, as I get an error saying that `$primary-1` is an undefined variable. How can I accomplish this without having to do all of the declarations twice?

Comment: Unrelated but just so you're aware, you can just write: `--primary-1: $primary-1;` Interpolation is totally necessary for just using a single variable as a value.

Comment: @StephenMIrving Ah okay. Was that changed at some point? I think I read somewhere that interpolation is required, and pretty much every example I can find online uses interpolation.

Comment: I don't think so, unless it was changed before I started using SASS. Interpolation would only be needed there if you were using the variable as a property, not a value all by itself. In your code you didn't include the `light-theme-variables` or `dark-theme-variables` snippets, maybe seeing that might help. Also, this link may help you as I don't actually think you'll need to use a mixin like assign-vars in order to do theming: https://css-tricks.com/css-custom-properties-theming/

Comment: This one also good: https://medium.com/@mwichary/dark-theme-in-a-day-3518dde2955a

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I ended up moving the variables into a [map](https://sass-lang.com/documentation/values/maps):

```css
$light-vars: (
  $font-name: 'Some Font',
  $primary-1: red
);

$dark-vars: (
  $font-name: 'Some Other Font',
  $primary-1: green
);
```

and created a helper mixin to assign them to CSS vars of the same name:

```css
@mixin assign-map-properties($map) {
  @each $key, $value in $map {
    @if (type-of($value) == 'string') {
      --#{$key}: '#{$value}';
    }
    @else {
      --#{$key}: #{$value};
    }
  }
}
```

which allowed me to accomplish what I need:

```css
@import 'assign-map-properties';

:root,
:root[data-theme='light'] {
  @import 'light-vars';
  @include assign-map-properties($light-vars);
}

:root[data-theme='dark'] {
  @import 'dark-vars';
  @include assign-map-properties($dark-vars);
}
```

Generated CSS:

```css
:root,
:root[data-theme='light'] {
  --font-name: 'Some Font';
  --primary-1: red;
}

:root[data-theme='dark'] {
  --font-name: 'Some Other Font';
  --primary-1: green;
}
```